# Error using VS 2017 and IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

My first time using Visual Studio 2017 and IIS, I'm getting an error and I can't seem to figure out why. I have added permissions to the folder being used but I still get the error. Im using windows 10 and IIS v 10. The project was created using iis 7 and another version of vs, would that be the reason for this error? Can someone please assist me?

```
Error: HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Comment: Please start by identifying the substatus code from the server log and posting the information here. It should be at the following location: %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC###\*.log. If you don't know how to do it please post the specific log entry.

Comment: I'm not seeing that file. But in researching I see where a user says this:project's properties page, switch to the "Web" tab and select "Use Local IIS Web Server". I'm not seeing the web option: references, build, accessibility, start options, msbuild options

Comment: On the start option i'm not able to select custom web server

Comment: What version of IIS and what operating system do you have? Please edit your original post to include this information.

Comment: Would the version cause the error

Comment: Sounds like you don't even have a complete IIS installation. Did you make sure all IIS components were enabled when you installed it? Besides, IIS and IIS Express are different if you don't know. State clearly which you use.

Comment: I'm using the built in Windows and IIS and not the built in VS IIS

Comment: I'm still having the issue can someone tell me what the issue is please